# Is there a way to avoid recursive make with nobase?

Tags: recursion, makefile, header, autotools, automake

I've got the following directory structure:

```
Makefile.am
src/
    mymod/
        mod.cc
        submod/
            submod.cc
inc/
    Makefile.am
    mymod/
        mod.hh
        submod/
            submod.hh
```

Using autotools, I'd like to distribute both a library made from `src` and the headers in `inc`. The top level `Makefile.am` looks something like

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = mylib.la
mylib_la_SOURCES=./mymod/mod.cc\
                 ./mymod/submod/submod.cc
SUBDIRS=inc
```

Then `inc/Makefile.am` has

```
mymod_includedir=$(includedir)
nobase_mymod_include_HEADERS=mymod/mod.hh\
                             mymod/submod/submod.hh
```

This works OK. I end up with whatever library stuff, and my headers get installed appropriately. However, I'd like to eliminate the recursion involved in the Makefile. The problem is that if I move the lines in `inc/Makefile.am` to the root directory, then I have to update the paths as follows:

```
mymod_includedir=$(includedir)
nobase_mymod_include_HEADERS=inc/mymod/mod.hh\
                             inc/mymod/submod/submod.hh
```

This results in my headers getting dumped as `$PREFIX/include/inc/mymod/mod.hh` and not `$PREFIX/include/mymod/mod.hh` like I want. I know I 
could do something like

```
mymodincludedir=$(includedir)/mymod
mymod_HEADERS=inc/mymod/mod.hh

mysubmodincludedir=$(includedir)/mymod/submod
mysubmod_HEADERS=inc/mymod/submod/submod.hh
```

but that's pretty painful, because there's a *lot* of subdirectories, and more subdirectories within the subdirectories (we're distributing a 3rd party's code that our own headers need). What I'd like to be able to do is either tell automake to just copy the directories in `/inc` to `$(includepath)` along with every subdirectory it encounters within, or tell it to only strip part of the path from the header files I'm listing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can find is Karel Zak's [`Makemodule.am` approach](http://karelzak.blogspot.ie/2013/02/non-recursive-automake.html) for which `nobase_` would work as you need.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? The Makemodule.am approach is already what I'm using. How can I use nobase_ this way? From what I understand I still have to specify the complete path, so I still encounter the same problems mentioned in my question.